# Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- skiptrace/internal/cruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Need some help with Macos Mojave, ruby-2.6.3 and rails-5.2.3

Can't start rails server cause error:

Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- skiptrace/internal/cruby
  /Users/tarasfediv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
  /Users/tarasfediv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in`block in require'
  /Users/tarasfediv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is related to https://github.com/gsamokovarov/skiptrace/issues/5 ...

Hope this helps.